# Submit a form with POST method in a custom file on Wordpress API response

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that gives a REST API. When a client requests [mydomain.com/wp-json/gateway/v1/redirect?key=value&key2=value2...](https://example.com/wp-json/my_api/v1/redirect) I want to redirect the user to a custom page on the same domain that submits a Form with POST method immediately and goes to another domain.

The page that contains the Form and is going to be submitted is just a `.php` file in my plugin directory that accepts some dynamic fields. Below is the page(file).

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    form.setAttribute("action", "https://nextDomain.com");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_self");

    var params = {
        Amount: '<?php echo $amount; ?>',
        MID: '<?php echo $merchant; ?>',
        ResNum: '<?php echo $resNum; ?>',
        RedirectURL: '<?php echo $callBackUrl; ?>',
        ResNum1: '<?php echo isset($resNum1) ? $resNum1 : ""; ?>',
        ResNum2: '<?php echo isset($resNum2) ? $resNum2 : ""; ?>',
        ResNum3: '<?php echo isset($resNum3) ? $resNum3 : ""; ?>',
        ResNum4: '<?php echo isset($resNum4) ? $resNum4 : ""; ?>',
    };

    for (var key in params) {

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }


    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is what the plugin looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Gateway Redirector
 * Plugin URI:  https://example.com/plugins/the-basics/
 * Description: Redirect payment requests to specified gateways
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Ako Salman
 * Author URI:  myDomain.com/
 * License:     GPL2
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain: Domain
 * Domain Path: www.myDomain.com
 */

add_action('rest_api_init', 'karabama_register_redirectors');

function karabama_register_redirectors()
{
    register_rest_route('gateway/v1', '/redirect', karabama_get_gateway_redirect_params());
}

function karabama_get_gateway_redirect_params()
{
    return [
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::ALLMETHODS,
        'callback' => 'karabama_gateway_redirect_callback'
    ];
}

function karabama_gateway_redirect_callback($request)
{
    // Here how can I redirect the user to .php file and submit the Form ?
}
```

Can anyone help me please how to handle it on the `karabama_gateway_redirect_callback` function?

Comment: the REST API is done to return JSON. if you want to customise the response and HTTP header, try [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: @Kaperto No problem, I could change to AJAX, but don't know how to implement the scenario of returning a custom page.